# mac software to merge folders

Tags: mac, merge

Today, [again](https://superuser.com/questions/117621/how-to-merge-and-not-replace-folders-when-copying-on-mac), I'm faced with troubles **merging folders on the mac**. But this time I don't want to discuss / try to solve the issue with *finder*.

So, just wondering once more, anyone have a good **software** out there, to recursively copy files from one folder to another without killing the destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [SyncTwoFolders](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/22644/synctwofolders) and I've never had a problem with it. Just be sure you have the options configured the way you want them before you start or you could unintentionally lose data.

There is also [FileSync](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/23023/filesync) which I have less experience with, you can also accomplish the same thing using [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/7032/carbon-copy-cloner) or [SuperDuper!](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/13803/superduper%21).

Comment: SyncTwoFolders seems perfect! Also, there is Unison: http://superuser.com/questions/117621/how-to-merge-and-not-replace-folders-when-copying-on-mac/207296#207296

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -avz --ignore-existing src dest
```

Comment: One might consider using cdto to open the terminal cd'ed to the current folder - http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/24105/%3E-cd-to-...

Comment: I did say **mac**, not **nix*. There are many distinctive advantages of having a GUI other than being pretty. Being able to analyze through integration (hear a song, see a video, read a text), individually select different actions on bulk operations such as this (pause, continue, delete just this one, hold that for later) and actually facilitating making progress, saving states to continue another day, just to name a few.

Comment: @Cawas: Those operations do not come for free; someone has to write the software to do that. On the other hand, rsync has already been written, and it works fine on OS X.

Comment: not asking for free. and thanks for your attention! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does Mac OS X's "ditto" solve this problem?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html

Comment: not anymore than rsync, as discussed with Ignacio.